# customer use wrong country for enjoying free shipping cart rules

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

The situation is i've setup a freeshipping for a country e.g Hong Kong, but the customers use a shipping address (address and city) in Korea, but they use hong kong as shipping country, and then they finally checkout with free shipping.

Do anyone know what any method, plugins, so i can avoid the above situations?

Comment: You can reject the order as suspected fraud

Comment: Other wise you can use the observer for the shipping address selection and check using google reverse geo api whether the address belongs to that country and if it is not belongs to that country you can disallow the customer to select shipping method